# Sagemaker Instance error: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, bigdata, amazon-sagemaker

I finally managed to train a regressor model with big data using dask and now I am getting this error and I am not sure what to do since I don't see any straight solution for Sagemaker instances.

I even tried increasing the instance size volumen.

Does anyone might know what to do on this specific case scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You already tried increase the volume size.

Check if you actually ran out of disk space:
`df -kh`
If so find what folder/files are taking up the space:
`du -ksh /some/folder`

Comment: Thanks for this, it was the model itself because I was increasing the instance size volume and still the model was requiring even more space.